# How to change locale environment variable?

Tags: environment-variables, locale

I have generated *en_US.utf8*, *et_EE.iso88591* and *ru_RU.utf8* localisation files. Now if I try to change any of the locale variables to a *ru_RU.utf8* or *en_US.utf8*, then this does not have any effect:

```
# locale -a
C
en_US.utf8
et_EE
et_EE.iso88591
POSIX
ru_RU.utf8
# LC_TIME=ru_RU.utf8
# locale | grep LC_TIME
LC_TIME="et_EE.iso88591"
# LC_TIME="ru_RU.utf8"
# locale | grep LC_TIME
LC_TIME="et_EE.iso88591"
#
```

However, if I change the *LANG=* variable, then all other variables but *LANGUAGE=* and *LC_ALL=* take the value of the *LANG=* variable. Is there a way to modify each locale variable separately? In addition, am I correct that locale variables aren't regular shell variables, but more like parameters to *locale* utility?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can set any locale category independently. `LANG` applies only to the categories that are not explicitly set.

`LANG` and `LC_xxx` are ordinary environment variables. They are not settings for the `locale` utility: the `locale` program isn't involved in any locale processing, it's just a small utility to report current and available locale settings.

When you write `LC_TIME=ru_RU.utf8`, this doesn't set an environment variable, only a shell variable. Shell variables are internal to the shell, they are not seen by other programs. Environment variables, on the other hand, are inherited by the programs that the shell starts. You need to export the variable to the environment as well:

```
$ LC_TIME=ru_RU.utf8
$ locale | grep LC_TIME
LC_TIME="et_EE.iso88591"
$ export LC_TIME
$ locale | grep LC_TIME
LC_TIME="ru_RU.utf8"
```

or directly

```
$ export LC_TIME=ru_RU.utf8
$ locale | grep LC_TIME
LC_TIME="ru_RU.utf8"
```

Comment: *"LANG and LC_xxx are ordinary environment variables"* How do you know that `LANG` and `LC_xxx` are environment variables? my testing shows that only `LANG` and `LANGUAGE` and `LC_MESSAGES` and `LC_ALL` are environment variables, while other variables like `LC_CTYPE` and `LC_MONETARY` are not environment variables (also, they are not shell variables)?

Comment: @rony_t You can look at the source code of applications and libraries, look at their documentation, or experiment with them. For example, compate `env LC_TIME=en_GB date` with `env LC_TIME=fr_FR  date` and `env PATH="$PATH" date` (obviously, pick locales that exist on your system). Obviously, each variable may or may not be set in a given process's environment. What testing did you do? Are you sure the application you used behaves differently based on `LC_CTYPE` (fairly common) and `LC_MONETARY` (pretty rare)?

Comment: In the terminal, I executed the `printenv` command to list the environment variables of bash, and only `LANG` and `LANGUAGE` and `LC_MESSAGES` and `LC_ALL` were listed as environment variables. I also executed the command `set -o posix` followed by the command `set` to get the environment variables and the shell variables of bash, and only `LANG` and `LANGUAGE` and `LC_MESSAGES` and `LC_ALL` were listed. So this means that  `LANG` and `LANGUAGE` and `LC_MESSAGES` and `LC_ALL` are environment variables and the rest of the locale variables are not, and also they are not shell variables.

Comment: @rony_t No. It means that _you_ have set the environment variables `LANG`, `LANGUAGE`, `LC_MESSAGES` and `LC_ALL`. (Either you did this explicitly or your distribution or your system administrator did it for you.) You can set an environment variable by any (syntactically valid) name! But some names are meaningful to some application, and some names aren't. `LC_MESSAGES`, `LC_CTYPE`, `LC_TIME` and so on are used by applications that care about the language of error messages, the character encoding, the time format, and so on.

Comment: @rony_t By the way your configuration is very strange. The setting of `LC_ALL` overrides all the other settings, so the value of the other locale variables doesn't matter. It's normally only used temporarily to force a program to use a given locale, it doesn't make sense to have it in your normal environment.

Comment: You are right, it depends on the distribution. The locale environment variables on Knoppix are different from the locale environment variables on Lubuntu. And `LC_ALL` is only set on Knoppix and not on Lubuntu.

Answer (score 7):

Under the Fedora/CentOS/RHEL based distros I believe you can change the locale to one of the locale's displayed when you run the `locale -a` command in this system file:

```
/etc/sysconfig/i18n
```

For example on my Fedora 14 system:

```
$ more /etc/sysconfig/i18n 
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
SYSFONT="latarcyrheb-sun16"
```

Under GNOME you can run the help app:

```
system-config-language
```

Which brings up this GUI:

[image: ss of lang. gui]

I think it's slightly different for the Debian/Ubuntu distros. I believe it's this file:

```
/etc/default/locale
```

I believe they're environment variables but not entirely sure how applications make use of them if at all.

#### References

- [What is a "locale?](http://www.iac.es/sieinvens/siepedia/pmwiki.php?n=Tutorials.LinuxLocale)
- [Character encoding and locales](http://tecnocode.co.uk/2011/08/27/character-encoding-and-locales/)

Answer (score 4):

On RedHat 6 at least, note that if LC_ALL is set, then setting other LC_* environment variables will have no effect, as LC_ALL takes precedence over all other LC_* environment variables.

```
[root@nbu76 bin]# LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
[root@nbu76 bin]# export LC_TIME
[root@nbu76 bin]# locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_IE"
LC_NUMERIC="en_IE"
LC_TIME="en_IE"
...
LC_ALL=en_IE
[root@nbu76 bin]# unset LC_ALL
[root@nbu76 bin]# locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
...
LC_ALL=
[root@nbu76 bin]# export LC_TIME=en_IE
[root@nbu76 bin]# locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME=en_IE
....
LC_ALL=
```

Answer (score 1):

In Debian systems, one can run `dpkg-reconfigure locales` to set the main language and make others available; then one can run `update-locale` to set the `LANGUAGE` environment variable in `/etc/default/locale` to have fallback languages.

Comment: `dpkg-reconfigure locales`, not `locale`

Comment: Thanks, @lauriys